# Kinematicbody2D touching Area2D?

Tags: godot

I want to detect if a kinematicbody is touching an area. I know how the body entered signal works and I know how to detect when the kinematicbody enters the area, but how can I continue to detect the collision, as long as the bodies are still touching?

I don’t want to run code just when the bodies first collide, I want to run it as long as they are touching.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to make a "pool" of objects in collision, such as:

```
func _on_body_entered(_body):
  colliding_pool.append(_body)

func _on_body_exited(_body):
  # this is optional and depends on your case
  if colliding_pool.has(_body) and is_instance_valid(_body):
    colliding_pool.erase(_body)
```

Then you can have in your loop to handle if there's collisions based on this pool not being  empty. You can also keep it on a single variable rather than an array of objects, this part is better to adapt based on your needs.